# How to Create Root Certificate for Azure VPN using MakeCert command specific to Azure VPN Requirements

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

How to Create Root Certificate for Azure VPN using MakeCert command specific to Azure VPN Requirements

**1)** Please mention specific command which could generate the certificate according to Azure VPN requirements 
and 
**2)** How to get the string value of the certificate to put it on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question have two parts, first command and second how to get the string value.

**1)** 
You can use below command and you can also change the CN= parameters to your naming if required.

**Server:**

> makecert -sky exchange -r -n “CN=AzureVPNRootCert” -pe -a sha1 -len
>   2048 -ss My “AzureVPNRootCert.cer”

You need to install the certificate locally and then export it in base 64 encoded format to see the signature string of the certificate to put it on Azure.

**2)**
Use certlm.msc **->** Certificate Local computer **->** trusted Root Certificate **->** certificates **->** choose your certificate **->** right click export **->** choose base 64 encoded format **->** save
Open the saved certificate in notepad and copy only the Certificate string to Azure.

**Bonus:** if you need to create client certificate to connect to Azure VPN, from more than one point.

**Client:**

> makecert.exe -n “CN=AzureVpnClientCert” -pe -sky exchange -m 96 -ss My
>   -in “AzureVPNRootCert” -is my -a sha1

[For official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/makecert)
[Original Post](https://scientistz.com/forums/topic/how-to-create-root-certificate-for-azure-vpn-using-makecert-command/)